# Unity3D or UDK or OPENGL from scratch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, opengl

I am just very confused which I should choose in terms of high end game development. The application that I am designing is pretty simple, requires some 3D, and some effects. I am looking at a game similar to ping pong, but with high textures and graphics. I will just need web services to submit high scores.

From my description, you can see that its pretty straight forward and I am confused whether I should use **Unity3D** or **UDK** or write the entire application myself with **openGL** (which will take a lot of time though).

If you had faced this dilemma before, and chose for a particular graphics engine, please provide your suggestions and reasons as to why that was better. It would be helpful.

Also, how can this affect in terms of *investment* and *revenue* ?

Comment: You'll need to look at the 3 close votes and their reasons to suss out the down-vote reasons "this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion".

Comment: @dlamblin I agree ! I am sure there are a lot of people on SO went through the exact problem, and experience counts greatly ! And that is why I had asked for opinions...

Comment: @Legolas: StackOverflow is not the place for discussion and opinions. It's a place for *facts*. Discussion and opinions go elsewhere. If your question is not answerable, then it is not a legitimate question for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No game written entirely in openGL is going to turn out being "pretty simple". So I think you answered your own question. Go with the simple option that has asset management and model support.

I think you earn a higher revenue with openGL all things being equal; iPhone development requires Unity iOS or iOS Pro licenses which cost about $400 and $1400 respectively per developer. Luckily that's a one time fixed cost.

Comment: Unity3D seems great. I am also looking at revenue perspective ...

Comment: That's off topic, it might be more s.tk/gamedev 's speed

Answer (score 1):

Between Unity3D and writing from scratch using OpenGL, I chose Unity3D without thinking twice. It's used by a large community, has plenty of easy to use features, is very well documented, and has a very good WYSIWYG development environment.

Comment: I see. What about revenue perspective and comparing these two ?